# How to get DateTime from JSON

Tags: angularjs, django, datetime, datetimepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker

How do I parse DateTime with Angular from my Django REST API? The date is stored in the following format `2016-07-07`. Angular UI Datepicker does not recognize it a proper date format, so my field becomes blank when I load the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh. I just had to create a new `Date` object based on my JSON string.

```
$scope.student.birth_date = new Date($scope.student.birth_date);
```